Error during SonarScanner execution in Jenkins
I’m trying to integrate sonar with jenkins, but the task execution are returning sonar scanner error.
Server version: sonarqube:7.9.2-community
Scanner version: 4.6.2
I’v tried jdk, 11, 15, 17 and 21.
Jenkins 2.463
Sonar config in Jenkins System.
Sonar config in Jenkins System.
Scanner config inside de task.
Scanner config inside de task.
Error Log
[DeployBack sonarqube] $ "C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SONAR_SCANNER\bin\sonar-scanner.bat" -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 ******** -Dsonar.projectKey=DeployBack -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=4d6d3e10920972244a4eac69d86471a22f8fec6f -Dsonar.java.binares=target "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.jenkins\workspace\DeployBack sonarqube"
WARN: Property 'sonar.host.url' with value 'http://localhost:9000' is overridden with value 'http://localhost:9000'
WARN: Property 'sonar.login' with value '4d6d3e10920972244a4eac69d86471a22f8fec6f' is overridden with value '4d6d3e10920972244a4eac69d86471a22f8fec6f'
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SONAR_SCANNER\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.6.2.2472
INFO: Java 17.0.11 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.sonar\cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SONAR_SCANNER\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 7.9.2
INFO: Default locale: "pt_BR", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=185ms
INFO: Server id: 7FE6487A-AZBLS_zeKfpxD82yl_rQ
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=58ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=115ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Project key: DeployBack
INFO: Base dir: C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.jenkins\workspace\DeployBack sonarqube
INFO: Working dir: C:\Users\Matheus Lima\.jenkins\workspace\DeployBack sonarqube\.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'DeployBack'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'DeployBack' (done) | time=51ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=70ms
INFO: Detected Jenkins
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=974ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: 15 files indexed
INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module DeployBack
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=34ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 4.411s
INFO: Final Memory: 10M/40M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.<init>(ActionParser.java:59)
    at org.sonar.javascript.parser.JavaScriptParser.<init>(JavaScriptParser.java:33)
    at org.sonar.javascript.parser.JavaScriptParserBuilder.createParser(JavaScriptParserBuilder.java:31)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor.<init>(JavaScriptSensor.java:136)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSensor.<init>(JavaScriptSensor.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:606)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponents(DefaultPicoContainer.java:587)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentsByType(ComponentContainer.java:290)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.completeScannerExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.getExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.AbstractExtensionDictionnary.getFilteredExtensions(AbstractExtensionDictionnary.java:67)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorExtensionDictionnary.selectSensors(ModuleSensorExtensionDictionnary.java:40)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:52)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:52)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:400)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:395)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:358)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @255e5e2e
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @255e5e2e
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    ... 64 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Build failed, project not deployed
Finished: FAILURE


I don't think there is a lot of interest for answering questions about Freestyle jobs. Those are dead. You might have more luck with pipelines.
